# Expo stripe library not working

Tags: react-native

I'm looking into switching to expo to develop my react native apps.

The only blocking point is that to get payment working with Stripe, you need to detach the project from expo which results loosing some of the interesting features Expo offers like helping to publish to apple and android stores, push notifications... Unless I'm wrong.

I tried this library which was promising but I can't get it working:

[stripe-expo](https://github.com/expo/stripe-expo)

Just tried it with the token creation example of the doc but I get empty answer from the createToken call:

Code

```
import React from 'react';
import { StyleSheet, Text, View } from 'react-native';

var stripe = require('stripe-client')('test publishable key I use normally');

export default class App extends React.Component {

componentDidMount() {

let card = stripe.createToken({
  card: {
    "number": '4242424242424242',
    "exp_month": 12,
    "exp_year": 2018,
    "cvc": '123'
  }
});
    console.log(card);

  }

  render() {
    return (
      <View style={styles.container}>
        <Text>Open up App.js to start working on your app!</Text>
      </View>
    );
  }
}
```

Response

```
Promise {
  "_40": 0,
  "_55": null,
  "_65": 0,
  "_72": null,
}
```

Any idea?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As it states in [documentation of stripe-expo](https://github.com/expo/stripe-expo#creating-a-token) `createToken` returns a [Promise](https://developer.mozilla.org/tr/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise).

> `stripe.createToken(...)` returns a Promise of a token object

You need to use it like this,

```
stripe.createToken({
  card: {
    "number": '4242424242424242',
    "exp_month": 12,
    "exp_year": 2018,
    "cvc": '123'
  }
}).then((token_object) => {
  console.log(token_object);
});
```

Comment: Stupid me... Thanks!